# Add session variable to inbound and outbound URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm designing a site using ASPx and IIS, where clients can sign up and then offer services to their clients. For example:

if you go to http://www.mywebsite.com you can sign up for your mywebsite.com account as a business owner. When you sign up, you are given a Site ID (Example: AA1234).

http://www.mywebsite.com/AA1234

What I want to do is always include the Site ID in every url (Inbound and Outbound). The Site ID is stored in a session variable based on the initial incoming request.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this - or a different design that works better than this?

Thanks

Comment: You could add it as a querystring value but this depends on the scenario, is it ok for users to modify the siteid value and see other sites or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is nebulous at best. However...

Wouldn't this be what cookies are used for?

In particular, if your user is authenticated (this is generally achieved in asp.net with an auth cookie), then at the server, you would have tools at your disposal that allow you to recognize the user and provide a different experience according to whatever criteria you choose. Most likely, these details might be stored in a database.

Comment: Sorry for being nebulous. Cookies are often a vexation.
If the client needs to send out a link to their users, they will need that Site ID included in the URL since new users won't have a cookie. Since our users will be sending out multiple sub pages with additional query string parameters and not simply going to mywebsite.com/SiteID, I would like to include the SiteID with Every link.

My understanding is that this should be possible using the URL Rewrite module for IIS but I can't find any documentation on adding custom session variables, or cookie values, to rewritten urls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in this topic: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1149673

The last response from BoulderBum is exactly what I needed.

Using the HTTP module I will take the /AA1234/ URL and point it to /Company/.

On the way out, I replace all instances of /Company/ with the site id again